# show more than one field in each cell of gridview using transform

Tags: c#, ms-access, select, gridview, transform

I have a table like below and fetch data from it using this query:

```
string sql = @"TRANSFORM First(Price)
SELECT    ChartDate
FROM      (SELECT     P.ChartTitle,
                  R.Price,
                  R.ChartDate
           FROM       tbl_Pd AS P
           INNER JOIN tbl_chart AS R ON P.ID = R.PdID  
           WHERE      R.ChartDate >= Date()-4)
             GROUP BY  ChartDate order by ChartDate desc
PIVOT     ChartTitle";
```

[image]

I put data in datareader and bind it to gridview
the result is this:
[image]

as you can see In tbl_chart theres a yes/no field, it's name NotExist.

how can I show a checkbox next to each price in gridview and bind notExist field to it? is it possible?
thanks a lot

Comment: Check this out : [Extending The DataGridViewCheckBoxCell To Include Text](http://www.murrayhilltech.com/articles/articles.aspx?key=7)

Comment: thanks but i think you didn't get my question, how can i fetch notExist field like price in above query and show "it is not exist" if notExist is false?

Comment: I am not really aware of the SQL pivot features, so I can't help. However, in the SELECT clause, you may replace "R.Price" by a function returning a negative value (i.e. -R.Price) if "NotExist" is true. Then, you may use the CellPainting event on the DataGridView to draw a checked/unchecked checkbox (according to ProductN sign) and draw the string equal to Abs(productprice).